# Styling AppBar/Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, toolbar, appbar

I'm currently working on a project where I've use the Android Toolbar. I need the standard functionality of the Toolbar with menu button (open the NavigationDrawer), settings etc which works fine.

The problem is, that I want to change the background of the Toolbar to be different in shape.

What I need is something like this (the App Bar consists of a rectangle and a triangle):
[image]

Is this possible with the standard Android Toolbar or is there a straight forward way to have this style and the standard functionality?
I am not sure how to achieve this.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I have tried the following by just adding a custom view I created to the AppBarLayout. The XML code looks the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <com.example.andy.test.CustomTriangleView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:shapeColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

So now the result looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make the part at the right of the triangle transparent? Because this would result in the design I like to achieve.

Comment: I think you should have to use image here.

Comment: Isn't there a different possibility? The problem with an image is, that the devices have different resolutions and the screen orientation can change.

Comment: Exactly there is issue with image. but Possibilities never dies!! for image alternative you can crate a custom view for polygon shape using surface view.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Do you have a good source / tutorial where I can find information on this?